# CartThrob Checkout as Member

Tags: cartthrob, ecommerce

I've set up a form on a site for super-admins to check out as other users, , making use of the member_id parameter found here - http://cartthrob.com/docs/tags_detail/checkout_form/index.html#member_id .  This is being used, essentially, to gift a purchase to these users, who need this purchase to do certain things on the site.

Here's the opening tag I have:

```
{exp:cartthrob:checkout_form 
id="checkout_form"
name="checkout_form"
return="/foo/bar"
gateway="ct_offline_payments"
required="first_name|last_name|phone|address|city|state|zip"
cart_empty_redirect="/foo/bar"
member_id="{segment_3}"
price="0"
}
```

However, when I use the checkout form, my orders are going in with the user id of the admin checking out.  I also notice that forum topics on the CT support forums with responses as recent as November, like this one - http://cartthrob.com/forums/viewthread/4636/ - reference a separate extension and custom fields to do this.

Does anyone have familiarity with doing this, or has used the parameter above effectively?

Comment: And you tried the [extension](https://github.com/CartThrob/extension-member-id-override) mentioned in that thread already without success?

Comment: I just ran into this problem without realizing it only works with subscriptions. Dang.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the member_id param only works when checking out with a subscription. So either the docs are wrong, or this is a bug. I think you'll have to use that extension to get it to work properly.

Comment: Was trying to avoid bothering you by posting this on here, thank you for the help Rob.